# Within IRIX : enumerate physical drives, and their capacity

Tags: unix, hard-drive, capacity

I'd like to know what physical disk drives are attached to an IRIX system, and the capacity (or at least geometry) of each disk. I can get the former through `hinv`, but that doesn't include capacity/geometry/etc. and my attempts to find this information have so far only yielded frustration.

Does anyone know the proper incantation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [getDiskInfo](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?cmd=getdoc&coll=0650&db=man&fname=1%20getDiskInfo)